# Count Query in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I am new to Mongo trying to write a query to count profiles where a specific value has been updated today. Below is an example of the documents I am working with:

```
_id:ObjectId("5a786fd3e6a123f9ab262c02")
tsAdded:Array
tsCrawled:Array
tsExtracted:Array
    0:Object
        value: 1517842389
    1:Object
        value: 1517842386
url:"https://example.net/subpage"
uri:"sgn://example.net/?ident=something"
uriSha1:"0bea74dce41fb8a7660b4e3b11693a387ab4brg7"
source:"companyname"
data:Object
```

I want to do a count on the data set so that I get only profiles where the 0 object in the 'tsExtracted' array is counted IF the date is today AND it was updated today. One query string I was playing with using Mongo mgmt. Studio is below.

```
{'tsExtracted.value': {$lte: ObjectId('5b4c34600000000000000000')}}.count
```

Where 5b4c34600000000000000000 is today's day beginning at 0h0m. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: are you intending to compare the date with objectId ? What is your mongo version ? You can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) to convert the objectId to date before comparison in 4.0 ?

Comment: Hello. I am using Mongo 3.6.3. I really want to know the date of 'tsExtracted.object.value[0]' (the first or '0' value in the index for that array) but I'm scratching my head and started to see if I could use ObjectId as a comparison but realize that is not possible.

Comment: Try `{'tsExtracted.value.0': {$lte: date in millis}}` More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-for-an-element-by-the-array-index-position)

Comment: It seems I don't even need to specify the index in the array. By simply limiting the date range to today, I naturally return all the documents with today's date in the 0 index for tsExtracted...

    `db.collection.find({ 'tsExtracted.value': {$gte: 1531699200} }).count()`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by using:

```
db.collection.find({ 'tsExtracted.value': {$gte: 1531699200} }).count()
```

1. I was originally doing a comparison on ObjectId which was wrong.
2. I needed to use epoch time for my $gte since tsExtracted.value uses it.